How to reinstall pgadmin and psql once deleted?
I'm diving into PostgreSQL this summer and decided to upgrade to the latest version (16) after using an older version (around a year old) for a bit.  Here's the thing: when I first installed PostgreSQL, it came bundled with pgAdmin and psql, which was super convenient.  In my haste to upgrade, I completely forgot you can upgrade and just deleted everything PostgreSQL related, including pgAdmin and psql. ‍
Now, when I try to install the new PostgreSQL 16, it skips installing those two tools because there's already a PostgreSQL folder in my Program Files directory(This is what I am guessing may not be the actual cause).  The problem is, I can't delete that folder because it says it's being used by another program (not sure which one!).  I'm worried that if I try to download pgAdmin and psql separately, it might mess something up.
Does anyone have any advice on how to get pgAdmin and psql installed alongside my new PostgreSQL 16 setup without causing any conflicts? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

"... because there's already a PostgreSQL folder in my Program Files directory ..." seems like deleting wasn't the best policy. On windows, always, ALWAYS, use the uninstall. That said, if you deleted parts of postgres and left some behind, you will likely need to finish the job deleting everything. You may also need a registry cleaner, (or a list of what entries the old install set). I'd focus on the complete removal and then start the install of 16 again. (Linux is so much easier from this standpoint). I don't run windows daily, so I can't help there. Good luck on the cleanup.
